# Filter out the [google-analytics-filters] tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Filters are a feature within the Google Analytics interface to exclude data from reports. This feature has very little to do with programming (except that you might need code to create the value to filter by, or if you want to create a filter programmatically via the management API) and questions about it are (IMO) off-topic.

A [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321006/google-analytics-filter-on-custom-dimension) quotes the [google-analytics-filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-filters) tag as evidence that questions about filters are on-topic. I think the easiest way to nip that argument in the bud would be to remove the tag. There are only 17 questions with that tag (and no tag wiki), most of them off-topic for various reasons. So while very little would be gained by deleting the tag it wouldn't be that much of an effort, either.

Comment: Don't let my 13.5k rep fool you, I have virtually no idea how housekeeping works on SO. Do I go ahead and remove the tags myself (as I said there are 17 questions) ?

Comment: Thanks for posting this burnination request and allowing the community to take a close look at it. Please note that burninations are not just tag removals - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid only mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. Flag/vote/edit/retag the posts after consensus is reached. For more info, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or the [unofficial SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).

Comment: Fortunately, Google hasn't sponsored this tag...

Comment: If most questions are indeed off topic, why there isn't one closed?!

Comment: @Braiam, I think largely because no-one bothers. GA questions are not popular and do hardly attract enough attention to gather enough close votes.